# Grunt include source not including the specified js files into the index.html

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I am trying to dynamically add all the javascript files lying within my Script folder into the index.html file. In order to perform the same, I am using GRUNT to include the files.
I have specified the below configuration in the grunt.js file:

```
{
includeSource: {
            options: {
                basePath: '../../Scripts/app',
                baseUrl: '/',
                templates: {
                    html: {
                        js: '<script src="{filePath}"></script>',
                        css: '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{filePath}" />',
                    }
                }
            },
            myTarget: {
                files: {
                    'tmp/index.html': '../../index.html'
                }
            }
        }
}
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-include-source');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['includeSource:myTarget']);
```

Also, inside the HTML file, I have added the below statement to include all the files within the script folder:

```
<!-- include: "type": "js", "files": ["Scripts/**/*.js"] -->
```

Thereafter, I run the command for the includeSource task as below:
grunt includeSource:myTarget

After running the statement the task completes and it says created a new file "tmp/index.html" as I had specified in the myTarget files source. However, the file created does not include the javascript files I have in my scripts folder. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: It could be a few different things. Double check your file paths. I was evaluating grunt plugins that do this recently and ended up choosing [fileblocks](https://github.com/rrharvey/grunt-file-blocks), so you might want to give that a try too.

Comment: Thanks @MKSafi. I tried the option specified by you and specified the grunt file block as fileBlocks: { dev: {files: [{src:'index.html', blocks:[{name:'libs', src:'Scripts/*.js'}]}]}}
Also, inside the index.html file, I have added the lines as :<!-- fileblock:dev libs -->
    <!-- endfileblock -->
But when I run the grunt command on command line, it says Cannot read property dev of undefined.
Am I using the correct comments in the index file